# drupal 7: custom design theme a block created with the Views module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

i create block with views module for Print Promoted to front page, this worked and i see result in my front page. this views worked with field and i print title, thumbs, content. now i need to custom this theme views for show in jquery content slider.

i click in advanced->theme->information i see this:

`field content revision:  views-view-field.tpl.php, views-view-field--title.tpl.php, views-view-field--frontpage.tpl.php, views-view-field--frontpage--title.tpl.php, views-view-field--block.tpl.php, views-view-field--block--title.tpl.php, views-view-field--frontpage--block.tpl.php, views-view-field--frontpage--block--title.tpl.php, views-view-field--block-1.tpl.php, views-view-field--block-1--title.tpl.php, views-view-field--frontpage--block-1.tpl.php, views-view-field--frontpage--block-1--title.tpl.php`

But i don't find any `.tpl.php` theme files for edit theme design using html and css. how to create custom design theme for print my result with this format:

```
<div id="content">
   <ul>
     <li>
        <div class="title">title1</div>
        <div class="thumbs"><img 1 ......></div>
        <div class="content">content1</div>
     </li>
     <li>
        <div class="title">title2</div>
        <div class="thumbs"><img 2 ......></div>
        <div class="content">content2</div>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Views 2 theming](http://drupal.org/node/352970) guide has already explained everything clearly. Just follow the steps there and it only takes just minutes.